# CKFetchRecordChangesOperation what is the returned clientChangeToken?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I am working on an app with `CloudKit` enabled and a local `CoreData` cache which syncs with  iCloud using `CloudKit`. I am using the `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` class to fetch new, changed and deleted records. The returned `CKServerChangeToken` is used for every consecutive fetch. `CKModifyRecordsOperation` is used to add and delete records.

If I add a record using `CKModifyRecordsOperation` the operation will return a new `CKRecord`. And if I then perform a new fetch using `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` the newly added record is fetched again which is unnecessary. Does anyone know how to prevent this behaviour?

I know there is a property called `clientChangeTokenData` of type `NSData` on the `CKModifyRecordsOperation` however the `clientChangeToken` returned from `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` is always `nil` for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the previousServerChangeToken there is no other mechanism for controlling what should be returned by the CKFetchRecordChangesOperation. It will just return the changes. This will include the changes that you have made yourself.

If that's a problem, then you could try using subscriptions instead. these will by default exclude the changes that are made by yourself.